# Finding $\int _0^a\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}dx$ to calculate arclength

Tags: calculus, integration

So I'm trying to find the arclength of $x^{0.5}$ and its tougher than I thought. Tried substitutions like $\dfrac{\cot^2x}{4}$ and some other trig subs but they got me nowhere. Any tips?
$$\int _0^a\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}dx$$

Edit:
This is what I got so far: $\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1+\left(\left(\sqrt{x}\right)'\right)^{2}}dx=\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}dx=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
t^{2}=1+\frac{1}{4x} & \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}},\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}\\
2tdt=-\frac{1}{8x^{2}}dx & x=\frac{1}{4\left(t^{2}-1\right)}
\end{array}\right]=\\\lim_{N\to0}-\int_{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}}^{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}}\frac{t^{2}dt}{\left(t^{2}-1\right)^{2}}=\lim_{N\to0}\int_{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}}^{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}}\left(\frac{1}{4\left(t+1\right)}-\frac{1}{4\left(t+1\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{4\left(t-1\right)}-\frac{1}{4\left(t-1\right)^{2}}\right)dt=\\=\lim_{N\to0}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left(t+1\right)+\frac{1}{t+1}-\ln\left(t-1\right)+\frac{1}{t-1}\right]_{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}}^{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}}=\\=\left[\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}+1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}-1}\right)-\frac{2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}}{1+\frac{1}{4a}-1}\right]-\lim_{N\to0}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}+1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}-1}\right)-\frac{2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}}{1+\frac{1}{4N}-1}\right]=\\=\left[\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}+1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}-1}\right)-8a\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}\right]-\lim_{N\to0}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}+1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}-1}\right)-8N\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4N}}\right]=\\=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}+1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}-1}\right)-8a\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}-0+0=\ln\left(4a\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+4}+2\right)+1\right)-8a\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4a}}$
But it doesn't seem right... any Ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with the substitution $1 + \frac{1}{4x} = u^2$?

Comment: I got $-\int_0^a\frac{t^2dt}{(t^2-1)^2}$. did I do something wrong? and if not, isn't this integral diverges for $a\geq1$?

Comment: I think you missed a factor $\frac{1}{4}$, and anyway with the substitution you have to change the integration value (the value $0$ and $a$ are transformed into something else). I think anyway it's better you just find the primitive and than a backward substitution (but i could be wrong about that).

Comment: (how many grammar mistakes... sorry for that, i can't edit xD)... Anyway what i meant was... you perform that substitution, keep in mind that the substitution includes changes in the integral extremes as well, finally decompose the function to be integrated using the partial fraction decomposition (of course depending on your skills and/or your background this could be a pain or not...). I don't know if it is the best way to compute that integral or not, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

If $u^2=1+\frac1{4x}$ then $x=\frac1{4(u^2-1)}$ and $\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{u}{2(u^2-1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^a\sqrt{1+\frac1{4x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{\sqrt{1+\frac1{4a}}}^\infty\frac{u^2}{(u^2-1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac18\int_{\sqrt{1+\frac1{4a}}}^\infty\left(\frac1{(u-1)^2}+\frac1{u-1}+\frac1{(u+1)^2}-\frac1{u+1}\right)\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac18\left[-\frac1{u-1}+\log(u-1)-\frac1{u+1}-\log(u+1)\right]_{\sqrt{1+\frac1{4a}}}^\infty\\
&=\frac18\left[\frac{2u}{u^2-1}+\log\left(\frac{(u+1)^2}{u^2-1}\right)\right]_{u=\sqrt{1+\frac1{4a}}}\\
&=\frac14\left(\sqrt{4a(4a+1)}+\log\left(\sqrt{4a}+\sqrt{4a+1}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a first substitution:
let u=  1+1/4x
yhen you will have to integrate: sqrt(1+u^2)du which is easy.
at the end you will get a formula with ln, tan inverse, and sec.
Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{a}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+4x}}+\frac{1+8x}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+4x}}\right)dx
 $$ for the first integral use the substitution $4x=t^{2}
 $ (the second is trivial) to get $$\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}dx=\frac{1}{4}\left(\textrm{arcsinh}\left(2\sqrt{a}\right)+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{1+4a}\right).
 $$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

Use [differential binomial](http://planetmath.org/integrationofdifferentialbinomial). Note that $$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}=0.5x^{-0.5}(1+4x)^{0.5}$$

Comment: I don't believe we're allowed to use this.